# Correspondent Bank query

Tags: usd-us-dollar, transfer

What is the correspondent Bank for a transfer in USD to Banque Internationale Arabe De Tunisie BIATTNTT

Comment: Have you tried asking that bank?

Comment: yes but they are not responding